# Three.js ortographic camera with particle system

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

Helo,

I'm trying to create a particle-system grid using an **ortographic camera** looking at rectange-faces drawn on **particle-system particles**. However my particles always get distorted, when they are close to the position (0, 0). I tested using normal, 3d objects, and in those cases this problem did not occur.

http://s27.postimg.org/6muzntr03/Stack_overflow_problem.jpg

How should I correct this behaviour?

*Hunyadix*